# calayer did not change according to UIView size in tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

**There is a view1(UIView) in Custom UITableViewCell in I want new size of view1(UIView) after AutoLayout to draw border**

UITableViewCell content is dynamic, hence I usedUITableViewAutomaticDimension for self resizing

I also use below methods but I get Original Size. I can not get new size of view1(UIView) after expanding

```
[self.tblView1 setNeedsLayout];
[self.tblView1 layoutIfNeeded]; 
[cell.view1 setNeedsLayout];
[cell.view1 layoutIfNeeded];

CALayer *rightBorder = [CALayer layer];
            rightBorder.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
            rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(cell.view1.frame.size.width-1, 0, 1, cell.view1.frame.size.height);
            [cell.view1.layer addSublayer:rightBorder];
```

rightBorder is draw but according to view1's(UIView) original size that is Width = 394 Height = 322 **not according to view1's(UIView) new size after layout size that is Width = 394 Height = 422**

Comment: Have you set `estimatedRowHeight` property of tableView?

Comment: @Rishab yes of course bro
self.tbl.estimatedRowHeight = 323;
    self.tbl.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Without above code I can not get result of Dynamic cell size

Comment: Have you written the code inside`initWithFrame:` or a custom method?

Comment: @Rishab are you taking abt below code yes I wright
rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(cell.view1.frame.size.width-1, 0, 1, cell.view1.frame.size.height);


if not then for what initWithFrame I should write

Comment: Chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144410/room-for-rishab-and-ankur-patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(tableView.tag == self.tblEditorialCalendar.tag)
{

UIView *leftBorder = [UIView new];
leftBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
leftBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIView *topBorder = [UIView new];
topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
topBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIView *rightBorder = [UIView new];
rightBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
rightBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIView *bottomBorder = [UIView new];
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
bottomBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[cell addSubview:leftBorder];
[cell addSubview:topBorder];
[cell addSubview:rightBorder];
[cell addSubview:bottomBorder];

[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[leftBorder(3)]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(leftBorder)]];
[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[leftBorder]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(leftBorder)]];

[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-3-[topBorder]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(topBorder)]];
[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topBorder(1)]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(topBorder)]];

[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[rightBorder(1)]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(rightBorder)]];
[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[rightBorder]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(rightBorder)]];

[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-3-[bottomBorder]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bottomBorder)]];
[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[bottomBorder(1)]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bottomBorder)]];


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
}

}
```

Another way is to use layout anchor (supported from iOS 9 and above) instead of VFL

```
[leftBorder.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:3].active = YES;
[cell.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:leftBorder.leadingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
[cell.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:leftBorder.topAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
[cell.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:leftBorder.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = YES;

[topBorder.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:1].active = YES;
[cell.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:topBorder.leadingAnchor constant:3].active = YES;
[cell.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:topBorder.topAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
[cell.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:topBorder.trailingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;

[rightBorder.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:1].active = YES;
[cell.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:rightBorder.trailingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
[cell.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:rightBorder.topAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
[cell.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:rightBorder.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = YES;

[bottomBorder.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:1].active = YES;
[cell.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:bottomBorder.leadingAnchor constant:3].active = YES;
[cell.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:bottomBorder.trailingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
[cell.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:bottomBorder.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
```

Or you could just take four view (as four borders) in your nib file and place them with proper constraints.